# Explicação sobre concatenação de variáveis em PHP

Tags: php, concatenação-de-string

Sempre fico em dúvida em como concatenar strings com variáveis em PHP. Tenho certa dificuldade em compreender a questão das aspas duplas ou simples.

Gostaria de uma resposta que esclareça o por que de utilizar uma ou outra e como por isso em prática.

Comment: Tudo isso está descrito no manual do PHP. Fazendo um complemento, a vírgula também pode ser usada como caracter de concatenação. Em testes de benchmark o uso da vírgula, no lugar de ponto, mostra-se mais performático.
É normalmente usado quando deseja aplicar micro-otimizações. Sobre o uso de aspa simples ou aspa dupla, prefiro aspa simples, pois, performaticamente é melhor.

Answer (score 15):

O operador de concatenação de *strings* é o ponto `.`

Por exemplo:

```
$ddd  = '34';
$fone = '32105691';

echo '(' . $ddd . ') ' . $fone;
```

Esse exemplo funciona igual com aspas duplas:

```
echo "(" . $ddd . ") " . $fone;
```

É assim que você concatena *strings* em PHP.

---

Outra questão é a diferença entre aspas simples e duplas. A *string* entre **aspas simples** não é processada, exceto pelos caracteres de escape. Por exemplo, se você quiser que a *string* contenha um caracter de aspas simples, precisará usar o caractere de escape `\`, assim:

```
$texto_com_aspas = 'Temos aspas aqui => \' <= e isto é bom.';
```

Se você usar o cifrão `$` ou os colchetes `{` e `}` com aspas simples, eles não serão interpretados (como acontece com aspas duplas). Eles vão permanecer literais, como são:

```
$texto_normal = 'A variável $texto_normal contém cifrão e {colchetes}.';
```

Se você usar **aspas duplas** vai ter que usar o escape para aspas duplas, para o cifrão e para os colchetes:

```
$texto_com_aspas = "Temos aspas aqui => \" <= e isto é bom.";

$outro_texto = "Temos cifrão e colchetes aqui => \{ \$ \} <= e isto é bom.";
```

Em ambos os casos, para obter uma barra invertida você vai precisar duplicá-la, pois na sua primeira aparição o caracter `\` é entendido como "escape":

```
$texto_com_barra_invertida = 'Uma barra: \\ e mais' . " outra barra: \\ beleza?";
```

Agora, a principal diferença é que usando **aspas duplas**, tanto o cifrão `$` quanto os colchetes `{` e `}` ativam o processamento de **interpolação** na *string*, através do qual o conteúdo de variáveis pode ser inserido no texto.

Por exemplo:

```
$ddd  = '34';
$fone = '32105691';

echo "($ddd) $fone";

// resultado => (34) 3210-5691
```

Isto só pode ser feito com aspas duplas. Com aspas simples ficaria assim:

```
echo '($ddd) $fone';

// resultado => ($ddd) $fone
```

---

Porém, em alguns casos precisamos usar colchetes, porque sem eles ficaria difícil dizer onde é que começa e onde é que termina a variável a ser interpolada. Veja:

```
$singular = 'peixe';
$texto = "Eu comprei muitos $singulars!";
```

Eu quero que apareça "*Eu comprei muitos peixes!*"

Porém, como é que o PHP vai adivinhar que a minha variável chama `$singular` e não `$singulars` (com "s" no final)?

Para esse caso, e outros mais complexos, usamos os colchetes:

```
$texto1 = "Eu comprei muitos {$singular}s!";

$texto2 = "Seja bem vindo, {$usuario->nome}!";

$texto3 = "Quantidade: {$item['quantidade']} Preço: {$item['preco']}";

$texto4 = "$propriedade => {$item[$propriedade]}";
```

Todos estes exemplos de interpolação necessitam aspas duplas.

---

Eu particularmente nunca utilizo aspas duplas. Eu sempre utilizo aspas simples. Já vi muito aspas duplas serem abusadas - com *strings* que ficam ilegíveis sem *syntax highlight*. Eu costumo usar a função [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php) quando quero interpolar. Meu conselho é: seja amigo dos outros desenvolvedores que irão trabalhar com você, e evite as aspas duplas.

Comment: Bem completa sua resposta. Great job!

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente, aspas simples e aspas duplas tem o mesmo efeito de concatenação de strings.
Em termos de performance, aspas simples são mais eficientes que aspas duplas (ela simplesmente concatena as strings, enquanto as aspas duplas tem uma dinâmica diferente de incluir cada substring em uma variável e aí sim concatená-las). Essa diferença no entanto tem pouca relevância hoje em dia, já que essa 'demora' adicional ao concatenar com aspas duplas é basicamente irrelevante.

```
$nomeCompleto = 'Nome'.'Sobrenome';
```

ou

```
$nome = 'Teste1';
$sobrenome = 'Teste2';
$completo = $nome . $sobrenome;
```

Answer (score 3):

A vantagem de usar aspas duplas é que elas interpretam valores. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
$nome = "Juca";
echo "Olá {$nome}!"; // Olá Juca! ?>
```