# implode() vs substr()

Tags: php, concatenação-de-string

Levando em consideração os códigos abaixo:

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 30000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $str .= 'STRING QUALQUER, ';
}
$str = subtr($str,0,-2);
```

e esse

```
$sArr = array();
for ($i = 30000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $sArr[] = 'STRING QUALQUER';
}
$str = implode(", ",$sArr);
```

Levando em consideração a performance, qual será a forma que tenha menos custo de processamento?

Achei em um código legado essas duas formas para fazer a mesma coisa.

`memory_limit` é um fator? através da minha pesquisa não encontrei nada, no manual do PHP sobre [implode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e [subtr()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) apenas mostra detalhamento de uso.

[Nesse link](https://www.sitepoint.com/high-performance-string-concatenation-in-php/) diz que fazendo com implode "**normalmente demora duas vezes mais que o operador de concatenação padrão**", mas substr() também teria que percorrer a string para fazer o corte, correto?

Relacionado: [Explicação sobre concatenação de variáveis em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7540/57801)

Comment: Teste com [substr](https://3v4l.org/EeLLV/perf#output) e [implode](https://3v4l.org/Y0AMm/perf#output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo um teste que fiz, a primeira opção é mais eficiente.
Testei seu código usando microtime e ao que parece, o primeiro teste leva menos tempo para ser processado.

O código usado foi:

```php
function microtime_float() {
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
  return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();

$str = '';
for ($i = 30000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $str .= 'STRING QUALQUER, ';
}

$str = substr($str,0,-2);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time_end_1 = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "A primeira solução levou $time_end_1 segundos.\n";

$time_start = microtime_float();

$sArr = array();
for ($i = 30000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $sArr[] = 'STRING QUALQUER';
}

$str = implode(", ",$sArr);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time_end_2 = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "A segunda solução levou $time_end_2 segundos.\n";

if($time_end_1 > $time_end_2) {
  echo 'O script 2 é mais rápido.';
} else {
  echo 'O script 1 é mais rápido.';
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826797/php-listexplode-vs-substrstrpos-what-is-more-efficient