# Ao usar método numa string, não está incluindo os parênteses "()"

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte método em uma classe:

```
public function cadastrar( $pastor ) {

    print $pastor->getIdMembro();  // IMPRIME 6
    $string = "INSERT INTO pastores ( idMembro ) VALUES ( $pastor->getIdMembro() ) ";
    print $string; // INSERT INTO pastores ( idMembro ) VALUES ( () ) 

    return $this->conexao->query( $string )  ? true : false;

}
```

Quando faço apenas print `$pastor->getIdMembro()`retorna o valor certo, mas quando uso em uma *string* não funciona e aparecem apenas `()`:

```
$string = "INSERT INTO pastores ( idMembro ) VALUES ( $pastor->getIdMembro() ) ";
```

Por que isso está acontecendo? Por que o resultado é `VALUES ( () )` e não `VALUES ( 6 )`?

**Obs**: não há erros no console.

Comment: coloque o $pastor->getIdMembro() dentro de { }

Comment: bom, funcionou. Mas porque APENAS nesse retorno e no SITE todo? O que está acontecendo aqui?

Comment: Relacionada: [Explicação sobre concatenação de variáveis em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7540/5878)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso é o que chamamos de **interpolação de *strings*** e só funciona no PHP se usado aspas duplas ou *heredoc*.

O interpretador do PHP, quando encontra uma *string* com aspas duplas ou *heredoc*, irá tentar avaliar o seu conteúdo e, para isso, irá percorrer a *string* da esquerda para a direita. Sempre que encontrar o caractere cifrão, `$`, o interpretador irá buscar o máximo de caracteres possível para construir o **nome** da estrutura que foi utilizada.

```
echo "Saudações $nome, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português";
```

O interpretador irá encontrar o caractere `$` e percorrer a *string* até o primeiro caractere que não fará parte do nome da estrutura, neste caso a vírgula, assim ele conseguirá inferir que a variável a ser exibida é `$nome`.

No caso de:

```
echo "Olá $pastor->getIdMembro(), tudo bem?";
```

O interpretador não irá parar no hífen pois entenderá que por se tratar de `->` ele deve continuar a análise para construir o **nome da propriedade** acessada. Assim, a análise do nome parará apenas quando chegar no parêntese, pois esse não pertence ao nome. Desta forma, o que o PHP faz é exibir o valor da propriedade `$pastor->getIdMembro` seguido de dois parênteses. Como `getIdMembro` não é uma propriedade do objeto (é um método), será exibida uma *string* vazia e, se seu servidor estiver devidamente configurado para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, será exibido o alerta `Undefined property: Pastor::$getIdMembro`.

Como você quer que os parênteses sejam interpretados de forma conjunta com o nome da estrutura, você precisa informar isso ao interpretador através do uso das chaves:

```
echo "Olá {$pastor->getIdMembro()}, tudo bem?";
```

Assim, a análise só irá parar ao encontrar a chave final, `}`, considerando a chamada do método como desejado.

Não usar as chaves ou usar é o que diferencia se estamos fazendo uma [**interpolação simples**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) ou uma [**interpolação complexa**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Com a **interpolação simples** você pode:

- Fazer interpolação de variáveis simples: `"Olá $nome"`;
- Acessar índices de um *array*: `"Olá $nomes[0]"`;
- Acessar propriedades de um objeto: `"Olá $pessoa->nome"`;

Com a **interpolação complexa** você pode:

- Fazer tudo o que a interpolação simples faz;

  - Fazer interpolação de variáveis simples: `"Olá {$nome}"`;
  - Acessar índices de um *array*: `"Olá {$nomes[0]}"`;
  - Acessar propriedades de um objeto: `"Olá {$pessoa->nome}"`;
- Acessar retorno de métodos: `"Olá {$pessoa->getNome()}"`;
- Construir dinamicamente os nomes acessados: `"Olá {${$campo}}"`;
- Acessar estruturas encadeadas: `"Olá {$pessoa->getEnderecos()[0]->getCidade()->getNome()}"`;
- Entre outras coisas;

Answer (score 6):

Acontece isso porque essa forma serve para interpolar VARIÁVEIS numa string, ai você ta tentando interpolar um MÉTODO. 
Ele retorna ( ) porque ele entende que $pastor->getIdMembro é um atributo (e busca esse atributo, oq retorna vazio), e então ele entende que os parênteses são apenas continuação da string.

Comment: hum, mas na linha de cima, quando faço apenas print $pastor->getIdMembro(), aqui NÃO há necessidade de concatenação. E funciona. Devo ter esse mesmo problema mais pra frente também. Obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: O seu método está correto, o problema foi vc colocar a chamada de um método dentro da string sem envolver ele com { }. Se fosse uma variável ou um atributo, teria funcionado corretamente.