# Por que esse código simples php não funciona ? - echo ("$var1 + $var2 = {$var2+$var1} <br>");

Tags: php

O CODIGO É:

```
echo ("$var1 + $var2 = {$var2+$var1} <br>");
```

sendo que ambas as variaveis sao reconhecidas. o compilador diz que o '+' nao era esperado, mas nao faz sentido...

php

Comment: Como comentei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356689/5878, ao verificar a interpolação de string, o interpretador do PHP irá buscar todos os caracteres a partir de `$` para construir o nome da variável acessada. A partir desse valor, você ainda conseguirá fazer algumas operações, que incluem acessar uma propriedade, chamar um método ou acessar uma determinada posição da sequência. Operações matemáticas não são permitidas.

Answer (score 1):

Essa interplação com `{}` não funciona assim no `php`, se quer fazer a operação faça fora dela e fora das aspas, assim:

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
echo ("$var1 + $var2 = " . ($var2+$var1));
```

Ou assim também:

```
echo "$var1 + $var2 = " , $var2+$var1;
```

E ainda, se quiser mostrar o nome da variável, use o caracter de escape "":

```
echo "\$var1 + \$var2 = "
```